# How do I find a first order approximation?

Tags: calculus

I have a question on Calculus, where I have to find the "first order approximation", on a function where:

```
sqrt[(C^2 + sin(h))], where C > 0, and h is small.
```

Please may someone help me to start this question, as I don't know how to start it.  I'm unsure on how to approach this question.

Thank you.

Comment: The first order approximation is the same thing as a tangent line approximation. So find the tangent line of $f(h) = \sqrt{C^2+\sin(h)}$ at $h=0.$

Comment: From the Maclaurin series expansion of $\sin(h)$, when $h$ is small, we know that $\sin(x)\approx h$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $f$ is a differentiable function then for small $h$ you know that the derivative is near the difference quotient:
$$
f'(x) \approx \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}
$$
so
$$
f(x+h) \approx f(x) + f'(x) \times h .
$$
That last equation is referred to as a "first order approximation". A second order approximation would add an $h^2$ term involving the second derivative. You will learn about that later in your course.

Comment: Thank you for the help, it's really helping me understand what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Also, your second equation is the first order approximation, how do I then relate this to my question involving C and h, or is the second equation the first order equation and in doing the steps my first order approximation won't include any C's?

Comment: what would the second order approximation look like?

Comment: @CharlieParker Write the next term of the Taylor expansion: $f(x+h) \approx f(x) + f'(x)h + (f"(x)/2)h^2$.

Comment: what is the relation of gradient descent and the first order approximation?

Comment: If $f$ is a function of several variables and you interpret the derivative correctly then this formula remains true. In gradient descent you want to choose a direction $h$ that maximizes this first order correction. But don't take this as a definitive comment. Ask another question if you must.

Answer (score 0):

If $h=0$ the expression equals $C$.  You are looking for the next term in the Taylor series near $h=0$.  We have $f(h) \approx f(0)+hf'(0)$ so you want to take the derivative with respect to $h$.  Your first order approximation will then look like $C+h($something).

Answer (score 0):

The 1st order linear approximation is: $L(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x= C + \dfrac{x}{2C}$ .