# A recursive strategy to generate an approximate solution to $xy' + (1+2x^2)y = 0$ (Part1)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider the following recursive strategy to generate an approximate solution to \begin{equation}
> \begin{aligned}
> xy' + (1+2x^2)y = 0 \quad (1)
> \end{aligned}
> \end{equation}
>   Rewrite (1) as \begin{equation}
> \begin{aligned}
> xy' + 1y = -2x^2y \qquad (2)
> \end{aligned}
> \end{equation}
>   Now assuming $x \rightarrow 0$ and discarding the right hand side of $(2)$, find a first order approximation $y_0$ as the solution to $xy'_0 + y_0=0$

I was hoping that typing this out will help me make sense of the question a bit but it did not. My question is: what is "first order approximation $y_0$"?

p.s. What would be a tag for this question?

Comment: Do you mean $xy'_0+y_0=0$ ?

Comment: See [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_approximation), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3295822/first-order-approximation-of-a-sqrt3-9?rq=1), and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2477599/how-do-i-find-a-first-order-approximation)

Comment: @LordVader007 Thank you! I have made the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question tells you what to do.  You are hoping that $x^2y$ will be small, so you can ignore it at the start.  You hope that the $y_0$, which will be a function of $x$, will be an approximation to the correct $y(x)$.  What you are doing is essentially fixed point iteration.  Having found a result $y_0$ for the equation with the right side zero, you will plug that into the right and get $xy_1'+y_1=-2x^2y_0$.  You can continue that iteration as long as it doesn't blow up and you don't get tired.  In favorable cases it will converge to the correct solution.

Can you solve $xy_0'+y_0=0?$

Comment: "you will plug that into the _left_  and get ..." Do you mean _right_ instead?

Comment: Yes I can solve the equation. The answer I got is: $y_0 = \frac{c}{x}$. Now... should I plug in this $y_0$ value into $xy'_1 + y_1 = 2x^2y_0$?

Comment: Then plugging in as I guessed in the previous comment, I got $y_1 = c_{0}x + \frac{c_1}{x}$

Comment: Yes, I meant plug that into the right.  Thanks.  I also dropped a minus sign in the iteration, which I think will just change the signs of some of the integration constants. Yes, $y_0=\frac cx$, but I don't think there is a second constant of integration, so $y_1=\frac cx-cx$.  Now you can plug this in and keep going.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input! I have somehow wrote down my interpretation for the rest of the answer in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3347832/a-recursive-strategy-to-generate-an-approximate-solution-to-xy-12x2y-0?noredirect=1&lq=1).  Do you mind taking a look at my answer and see what you think? Of course, no obligation. :)