# A recursive strategy to generate an approximate solution to $xy' + (1+2x^2)y = 0$ (Part2)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is a continuum to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3347825/a-recursive-strategy-to-generate-an-approximate-solution-to-xy-12x2y-0).

> ... Now substitute $y_0$ on the right side of $(2)$ and solve for $y_1$. $$xy_1' + y_1 = -2x^2y_0$$
>   Continue this process until you obtain $y_2$. How does $y_2$ compare with the series solution to $(1)$ obtained by Taylor series expansion about the point $x_0=0$? Can you use this series to motivate a modification to the series expansion $y = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_nx^n$ that would be appropriate to use to obtain a series solution to $(1)$?

Can someone translate this into a language that I can understand? First of all, I don't know how to get $y_0$ (Part1), and so of course, I don't know how to solve for $y_1$ and $y_2$. After that I will consider the next question (use this series to motivate a modification...).

Thank you for your help in advance!

Edit: Now I can get $y_0 , y_1, y_2$. However, I still don't understand what it means by "motivate a modification to the series expansion ... that would be appropriate to use to obtain a series solution to $(1)$".

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to some insight given by Ross Millikan from the previous post. I finally could make some sense of this problem.

To begin with, the Taylor expansion to the equation $(1)$ is $$y = \frac{c}{x}(1-x^2+\frac{x^4}{4}-\frac{x^6}{3}+ \cdots)$$
$$ \ = c(\frac{1}{x}-x+\frac{x^3}{4}-\frac{x^5}{3}+ \cdots)$$

From calculating $y_0, y_1, y_2$ recursively from the previous post, we get:

$$y_0 = \frac{c}{x}$$
$$y_1 = c_1x+\frac{c_0}{x}$$
$$y_2 = c_cx^3+c_bx+\frac{c_a}{x}$$

Although it doesn't tell us about the coefficients  of $x$'s, it does tell us about the powers of $x$ terms.

This is how far I have got. I will update my answer once my prof upload (hopefully) the answer or when I get my grade back.

Answer (score 1):

Taylor series are defined as only having powers of $x$ that are nonnegative.  Your solution for $y_0$ is $\frac cx$, which has a negative exponent.  You probably had some previous questions with a different differential equation where you followed the same procedure, but $y_0$ was constant or a power of $x$ and you got a solution in the form of a Taylor series.  Now you have a similar outcome, but the result is $\frac cx$ times a Taylor series.  The modification is to start your sum at $n=-1$ instead of $n=0$.  A [Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) is allowed to have infinitely many terms with negative exponents.  You may want to have the lower limit of summation be some finite negative number.